# VkBotLongPoll примеры ботов

Tags: vkontakte-api

```
import requests
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random

bot_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="Токен сообщества-бота, доступ ко всему")
bot_api = bot_session.get_api()
while True:
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bot_session, "id сообщества-бота")
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
        #...
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as timeout:
        continue
```

У кого есть **РАБОЧИЕ** боты для **ГРУППЫ В БЕСЕДУ**,  **чтобы бот только отвечал в БЕСЕДУ**.
Перерыл пол интернета ничего не нашел рабочего

Comment: В документации в api python ничего нету. Я просил помощи а не тыкать меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример рабочий. А чтобы бот отвечал только на события из беседы, можно проверять флаг `event.from_chat`.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


vk_session = VkApi(token='access_token')          # Подставьте свой
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'group_id')  # Подставьте свой
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        vk.messages.send(
            message='Test message',
            peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'],
            random_id=get_random_id(),
        )
```

Не забудьте включить `Long Poll API` в настройках сообщества и подписаться на нужные события:

[image: Включение API]

---

[image: Подписка на события]

Comment: Я все ему выдал и он не хочет ничего отвечать.

Comment: @JleUTeHaHT В беседе право на чтение выдали? (или права администратора)

Comment: Дал ему админку и доступ к переписке